# Offline DB Restore on running Edge server

Tags: perforce

We have a situation where we want to re-seed the edge offline database from a checkpoint of the live DB. I understand there will be downtime as a dump of the online edge database will have to be performed.

Can someone help me with the commands "how to dump the database/tables" and "how to restore the offline database from the dumped file"?

FYI-- We are runing SDP 2017 version

Regards,
Manoj

Comment: What kind of help do you need?  It sounds like you've already found some documentation on the process, which would presumably already have specific instructions on what commands to run.  Are you looking for more information on those commands?  Did you try to run them and get stuck?

Comment: Windows or Linux host? The instructions are somewhat different for the two OS configurations.

Comment: It's linux  (RHEL) host machine.